# Cannot upgrade Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

I have closed every window, restarted the computer. But Eclipse is telling me: "C:\Program Files\android-sdk\tools is being accessed....I even deleted the directory but I still get : how to fix?

> Failed to rename directory C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.

Comment: Have you tried starting Eclipse with administrator privileges?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have had this problem on Windows too. Instead of updating it through Eclipse, try the stand-alone option:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Open a Command Prompt window (ideally in
   Administrator mode)
3. Run the command "android"

If you have the SDK tools directory in your path it will open the same UI you get in Eclipse but without additional file locking. If it is not in your path have a look in `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools` and run "android.bat" from there.

Also, once you have updated the SDK, don't forget to fire up Eclipse and, on the Help menu, click "Check for Updates". You may well find the ADK Eclipse plugin needs to be updated too - this often goes in step with SDK updates.

Answer (score 2):

Supposedly, if you use the `SDK Manager.exe` program rather than `tools\android.bat`, it works. However, I've never had any luck with that.

My traditional approach has been:

- Duplicate the `tools\` directory to create a `foo\` directory
- Adjust your `PATH` and other environment variables to point to `foo\`
- Run the `tools\android.bat` out of `foo\`
- Do the upgrade, which should work
- When done, close out of the SDK and AVD Manager, revert your `PATH` and such to point back to `tools\`, and get rid of the `foo\` directory

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that adb is restarting with the computer.  Try `adb kill-server` before upgrading

Answer (score 0):

Another simple fix:

Close Eclipse. Open the directory where your SDK is located (C:\Users\user35\android-sdks) and run SDK Manager (as Administrator).