# Eclipse not updating android sdk list

Tags: android, eclipse

Okay I want to upgrade my Android SDK from 2.2 to 4.0.3. So, I downloaded the Android SDK 4.0.3 using direct link http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-15_r01.zip, and then extracted in my `Android\android-sdk\platforms` directly.

When I open my SDK manager through eclipse it fails to detect the new version and only detects the 2.2 one. But when I open it through going to `Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe` it is well detecting my new version. Please help I am unable to create new 4.0.3 projects.

I got this answer [Cannot upgrade Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988929/cannot-upgrade-android-sdk) but this doesn't helps me when i click on "Check for updates" it shows "No updates available".

Comment: Pl check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469723/eclipse-adb-and-ddms-not-detecting-android-emulator/8799227#8799227

Might help in creating AVD..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//try to download r14 and use it

Eclipse IDE

```
Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) or greater
Note: Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) is no longer supported with the latest version of ADT.
```

so whats your eclipse version is it 3.5.

Comment: I am having 3.7. Thanks for the help but I found the solution. I dont know but somehow I was having Android SDKs in both D: and E: and only Android of E: was being used by Android. So I moved all my android files from D: to E: and it detected. Now the problem it is unable to create AVD.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is very complex and every update for software used by eclipse, generally needs to be installed through eclipse. For updating the Android SDK, I would first delete the install package you just added, then open up your version of Eclipse, click on the "Window" tab, then select the Android SDK Manager and install it via that method.

Comment: But I don't like downloaded from the SDK manager, because there is no resume support and I am having a slow internet connection. Anyways my problem is solved.