# I can't update android SDK (API)

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

What is happened ? I can't update android `SDK` in my adt-bundle folder.

My computer is Windows 7 32 bits. In android eclipse, Max API is 17.

So, I wanna to upgrade my `SDK`, API to 21.

But I occur error box

> Failed to rename directory E:\Installar\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\platform-tools to E:\Installar\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01.

Comment: Even if you run the SDK as admin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot upgrade Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988929/cannot-upgrade-android-sdk)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't upgrade Android SDK Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559682/cant-upgrade-android-sdk-tools)